# A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in Syncfusion.SfPdfViewer.WinRT.DLL

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, syncfusion

Im getting this exception:
"A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in Syncfusion.SfPdfViewer.WinRT.DLL" in a windows store app project.

it happens when im in my main page, and press a tile that navigates to a new page that opens a pdf then go back to main page, and press tile again to open the same pdf
it doesn't allways happen, but when it does, its when i try to open the pdf a second time.

in my pdf page i have this section

```
public PdfPage()        
{  
    this.InitializeComponent();
    //NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled; 
    this.DataContext = this;
}



protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    //DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Portrait;
    backButton.IsEnabled = false;
    backButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    document = e.Parameter as Document;


    if (document.Source == SourceType.Join)
    {
        pdfTrace.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        pdfShare.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    }


    var error = false;
    try
    {


        await GetFile();


        //DispatcherTimerSetup();
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        //await SetFileTraces("open", document.GetFullPath());
        backButton.IsEnabled = true;
        backButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e1)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("pdfpage.cs 87    " + e1.Message);
        error = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("PDFpage.cs  90 " + e1.Message);
        ShowMessageDialog("Connection Lost!");
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(LoginPage));
    }

    if (error)
    {
        await new MessageDialog("The file does not exist!", "Error").ShowAsync();
        Frame.GoBack();
    }

}


private async Task GetFile()
{
    try
    {
        backButton.IsEnabled = false;
        //IsLoading = true;

        var path = document.GetFullPath();
        byte[] bytes = null;

        if (document.Source == Enums.SourceType.Join)
        {
            JoinService joinService = new JoinService();
            string nameNoExt = document.Name.Remove(document.Name.Length - 4, 4);
            string handle = document.Handle;
            bytes = await joinService.GetFileAsync(handle);
            Debug.WriteLine("JOIN");
        }
        else
        {
            bytes = await gappService.GetFileAsync(path);

        }

        pdfDocument = new PdfLoadedDocument(bytes);
        pdfViewer.DocumentLoaded += (sender, e) =>
        {
            try
            {
                pdfViewer.ViewMode = PageViewMode.FitWidth;

            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("pdfpage.cs 128    " + e1.Message);
            }
        };
        pdfViewer.LoadDocument(pdfDocument);


        backButton.IsEnabled = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("PDFPage   175  " + e.Message);

    }

}
```

in my output window i get

"A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in Syncfusion.SfPdfViewer.WinRT.DLL
pdfpage.cs 128    Input string was not in a correct format."

in the exception stacktrace i have this

"

> at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource
>   resource)    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey
>   key, TValue value, Boolean add)    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
>   at Syncfusion.Windows.PdfViewer.PdfDocumentView.IncludeCanvas(Int32
>   pageIndex, Int32 width, Int32 height)    at
>   Syncfusion.Windows.PdfViewer.PdfDocumentView.d__54.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.b__4(Object
>   state)    at
>   System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeCore()

"

and my exception message is: ""Value does not fall within the expected range." and sometimes {"Value does not fall within the expected range."}

im using Syncfusion 8.1 Controls for WinRT XAML version 12.2.0.36
(it also appears to happen more times when i test in the simulator)

Answer (score 1):

Tried to recreate your problem to navigate between two pages with syncfusion PDFViewer control in one page and it is working fine for me.

Report this issue to Syncfusion support and get your problem solved. You can contact Syncfusion support through [this link](http://www.syncfusion.com/Account/Logon?ReturnUrl=%2Fsupport%2Fdirecttrac)